# Name formatting in python with string splits

Tags: python-3.x

I have gotten mostly through this assignment but I am stuck as to obtain the proper outputs.

This assignment wishes that if the inputs are a full name, that the outputs are "last name, first initial. last initial. If the input was Stacy Estel Graham, the expected output should be Graham, S.E.

"Many documents use a specific format for a person's name. Write a program whose input is:

firstName middleName lastName

and whose output is:

lastName, firstInitial.middleInitial."

```
full_name = input()
mod_name = full_name.split(' ')
last_name= mod_name.pop(-1)
mod_name.join('.')
print(last_name)
print(mod_name)
```

I am completely lost on how to proceed.

Comment: change your last print statements to : `print(last_name + ", " + mod_name)`

Comment: is it `last name, first initial, middle initial`? or `last name, first initial, last initial` ?

Comment: lastname, first initial, last initial. and the inputs involve various names,

Comment: @RandallMcGrath, looks like the name can be just `last name` or `first name last name` or `first name middle name last name` or `first name middle name1 middle name2 last name` or any combination of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use '.'.join() to get the initials added.

To extract only the first char from the name, you can do `mod_name[i][:1]` where `i` is the index from 0 until last name - 1.

You can do something like this:

```
full_name = input('Enter your full name :')
mod_name = full_name.split(' ')
temp = '.'.join([mod_name[i][0] for i in range (0, len(mod_name) - 1)])
if temp == '':
    print (mod_name[-1])
else:
    print (mod_name[-1] + ', ' + temp + '.')
```

Here are some of the sample runs:

```
Enter your full name :Stacy Estel Sugar Graham
Graham, S.E.S.

Enter your full name :Stacy Estel Graham
Graham, S.E.

Enter your full name :Stacy Graham
Graham, S.

Enter your full name :Graham
Graham
```

Comment: This code worked except the input brackets had to be empty .

Comment: Excellent. If this worked for you, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as complete. Please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```py
def format_name(name):
    names = name.split()
    return f"{names[-1]}, {''.join([f'{i[0]}.' for i in names[:-1]])}"
```

---

Examples:

```
format_name('Stacy Estel Graham')
# > 'Graham, S.E.'

format_name('Randall McGrath')
# > 'McGrath, R.'
```

Answer (score 0):

this code help you,but middle name is must for every person for creating your desire output

```
import re
s="Stacy Estel Graham"
words=s.split()
k=re.findall("[A-Z]",s)
p=words[-1]+","+k[0]+"."+k[1]
print(p)
```

Output:

```
Graham,S.E
```

Comment: some inputs do not inlcude middle name. I forgot to mention that. some inputs have middle name while some do not. the assignment tests with  4 inputs. 2 have first, middle, and last name while the other 2 inputs have only first and last.

Comment: what is your desire output for those has first and last name?

Answer (score 0):

Not with `re` :

```
full_name = input()
mod_name = full_name.split(' ')
last_name= mod_name.pop(-1)
first_inital = mod_name[0][0]
if len(mod_name) >= 2:
    middle_inital = mod_name[1][0]
    print(f'{last_name}, {first_inital}.{middle_inital}')
else:
    print(f'{last_name}, {first_inital}.')
```

You can use string indexing and `f'` string format.

Input:

```
Hello World Python
```

Output:

```
Python, H.W.
```

Comment: add a `.` at the end of the print. The requirement is to have a `.` at the end as well. While this is great, it may not work if just first and last name were given.

Comment: Oh, edited, thank you. and about the second one, I will think about it

Comment: Now fixed the second part too!

Comment: this is what worked after arrows >>full_name = input()
mod_name = full_name.split(' ')
temp = '.'.join([mod_name[i][0] for i in range (0, len(mod_name) - 1)])
if temp == '':
    print (mod_name[-1])
else:
    print (mod_name[-1] + ', ' + temp + '.')

Comment: I appreciate the answers but I want to make sure I understand why the code works. seems like there's so many ways to go about this. I will have to double down on study time to get through this class.

Answer (score 0):

```py
full_name = input()

mod_name = full_name.split(' ')
temp = '.'.join([mod_name[i][0] for i in range (0, len(mod_name) - 1)])

if temp == '':
    print (mod_name[-1])

else:
    print (mod_name[-1] + ', ' + temp + '.')
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the first statement in the argument to `input`.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?